# jquery find method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called using an anchor inside a form, and I need to get the values of the inputs inside the same form to perform certain actions. Problem is, the result is always `undefined`.

Here's the code :

```
$('#create_alert').live('click', function(e) {
    var form = $(this).parent().get(0);

    var id = $(form).find('input[name="id"]').val();

    alert(id);
});
```

.. and the context :

```
<form name="create_alert">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
<a href="#" type="text" id="create_alert" class="search-submit">CRIAR ALERTA</a>
</form>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/ayzEz/ Please post code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it alerts "1": http://jsfiddle.net/cyD4P/

Comment: That makes it even more strange .. I can't figure out why it ain't working in mycase .. What could it be, id / name conflicts?

Comment: yup, must have some similar name in another input, although names aren't required to be unique neither there was another similar name inside the form .. anyway, it works now, thanks for the tip :)